# Many-to-One relationship with JDO and GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have searched all over the site
But there even not one example of how to make with jdo a many to one relation ship.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships

but I couldn't find out how to do it.

lets say I have this DB:

```
Cars(CarID,OwnerID,...)
Owner(OwnerID,...)
```

And I want to create new entity for a new car - how can i make it?

I dont want to make another entity for an owner if the owner is already on the db but if he is not I like to make new owner.

Thanks for any example code or blog link on how to deal with it.

EDIT:
Its seems like you think its bidir relationship.
So i think you didnt understand me well.
lets say we are not talking about Car and Owner
we are talking now on Genre and Song

Genre-dont need to know about Song!
Song need to know his Genre!

my classes are:

```
public class Genre {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
String genre;
```

}
AND:

```
public class Song{
long id;
    @Join(name="GENRE_JOIN")
Genre genre;
```

}

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All of the GAE docs say refer to the DataNucleus JDO docs for full details, so I don't see why they should provide examples of everything. Since your relation is *seemingly* (not that you define it) a 1-N BIDIR relation at Owner side, and N-1 BIDIR at Car side then http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/orm/many_to_one.html
The JDO spec would also have ample examples.

Comment: "Thanks for any example code or blog link on how to deal with it."

i cannot get from the site how to make it!
when i put the @Join(name="ACCOUNT_USER")
i get this error:
The attribute name is undefined for the annotation type Join

if you will put full example of how to do it, its will be usefull for all the community...
thanks in advance

Comment: The page does give a complete example. Perhaps if you start by posting your classes in your question then people don't have to spend time guessing

Comment: So you want to represent it as a N-1 *foreign key* relation, which that page says very clearly treat it the same as a 1-1 UNI FK Relation, as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/orm/one_to_one.html#uni which also gives a complete example

Comment: does it make duplicate entities on the Genre table?

Comment: No. Obviously not, unless you write bad persistence code of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Owner {
    @Persistent(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Car> cars;
}

class Car {
    @Persistent
    private Owner owner;
}

Car car = new Car();
//search for the owner.
car.setOwner(owner);
```

Comment: this example is not good for me since its bidirectional.
i want that cars will know about owner. but owner will not need to know car!.

Comment: lets say we are not talking about cars and owners!
we are talking about songs and genre.
so its N-1 relationship. genre dont need to know all the songs. but song need to know his genre!